# Passing variable for module import and use

Tags: python, arrays, variables, parameter-passing, python-module

so I am trying to use a variable brand which is selected by the user. The variable is then to be used to call a given module in Python. currently on line 7 you can see 'apple.solutions()'. However, I essentially want to be able to use something on the lines 'brand.solutions()' - although I know this will not work as it requires the attribute. I am looking for a solution to select the module based on the variable brands. I would appreciate any solutions or advice. Thanks,

Main program:

```
import apple, android, windows

brands = ["apple", "android", "windows"]
brand = None

def Main():
    query = input("Enter your query: ").lower()
    brand = selector(brands, query, "brand", "brands")
    solutions = apple.solutions()
    print(solutions)
```

Apple.py Module File (same directory as main program):

```
def solutions():
    solutions = ["screen", "battery", "speaker"]
    return solutions
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import apple, android, windows

brands = ["apple", "android", "windows"] 

def selector(brands, query):   
    if query in brands:
        exec("import %s as brand" % query)
    else:
        brand = None

    return brand


def Main():
    query = raw_input("Enter your query: ").lower()
    brand = selector(brands, query) 
    solutions = brand.solutions()   
    print(solutions)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

I have a simple way by using the `exec` function to dynamically import models

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your advice! I currently have a selector function which deals with the error handling side, would it be possible to implement the exec function with a predetermined brand variable? Current code: http://pastebin.com/c876C3Qn Thanks, Sam

Answer (score 0):

What you may be looking for is a call to your Main() function:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     Main()
```

The code above should go at the end of your main program. It checks whether the main program is imported or not, then executes the `Main()` function if it is not imported and runs as a standalone program.